# how to make text within a div unhighlightable

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, gamequery

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers simply did not work

I tried adding the jquery disable selection code here, it did not work

```
  jQuery.fn.extend({ 
    disableSelection : function() { 
            return this.each(function() { 
                    this.onselectstart = function() { return false; }; 
                    this.unselectable = "on"; 
                    jQuery(this).css('user-select', 'none'); 
                    jQuery(this).css('-o-user-select', 'none'); 
                    jQuery(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none'); 
                    jQuery(this).css('-khtml-user-select', 'none'); 
                    jQuery(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none'); 
            }); 
    }
```

});

I tried adding user-select none to it, but it didn't work

```
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: moz-none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

and am considering making a transparent alphabet in paint (would be a bit resource intensive)

the reason I need the text to be unhighlightable is it's a game that uses gamequery, and when the objects are dragged, the text within the div is highlighted, which makes it look really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is similar to [How can I stop text from being selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469900/how-can-i-stop-text-from-being-selected)

helpful link:

http://chris-barr.com/2009/02/disable_text_selection_with_jquery/